# Improving complex

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am having a confusion. If I have to prove,

Now, in this, if I calculate the limit,

By this can I Say that this does belongs to big-o(4n).
Be
Which is not true for any value of n.
Is this the correct way of proving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to definition, if there is a `c` constant which hold for `f(n) <= c*g(n)`, then `f(n)` belongs to `g(n)`.
so indeed, `(2n+1)` belongs to `O(4n)`  because there are the constants 1 and 4 which hold:
`1*(2n+1) <= 4n <= 4*(2n+1)`

(This is also show that `(4n)` belongs to `O(2n+1)`. this is because they are both `O(n)`)

Comment: Let's say I am asked to prove this relation. Now, I start by taking out the limit. The answer given by the limit doesn't satisfy the relation. Then, how do I write it? Do I write, since it will be satisfied for other values, therefore, the relation is true?

Comment: since THERE IS a constant that satisfy the relation. it doesn't need to hold for ANY constant, it is enough that exists one constant. in this case, `(1/10)*n <= 1*(2n+1) <= 4n <= 4*(2n+1) <= 10*n` so these both function are `O(n)`

Comment: Got it thanks. So, then why do I take out the limit? Can't I directly proceed by the above method, i.e. by the inequality method?

Comment: Here it was easy to see that `1*(2n+1) <= 4n`. Sometimes it is not very simple to be convinced that some constant hold the inequality and to prove the inequality you need to use the limit

Answer (score 1):

A constant doesn't influence the `O` time complexity.

I mean `O(2*n) = 2*O(n) = O(n)`.

If `2n+1` is in `O(4n)` => `2n+1` is in `O(n)`.

Because `lim(n->infinite)(2n+1)/n = 2` is a finite number => `2n+1` is in `O(n)`.

Comment: That's all I need to show in order to show it as belonging to O(n)? No inequaltiy things?

Comment: If that limit `f(n) / g(n)` is finit ( `2n+1/n` ) => `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` ( `2n+1` is in `O(n)` ). This approach is just another form for the definition containing `c`.

Comment: After this, don't I have to find out the value of n0 by using this value of c?

Comment: Yes, if you use this approach you don't need the other approach. They are equivalent if you think in terms of Mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best constant. As you've observed, `2` is not going to work. For every `epsilon > 0`, however, the constant `2 + epsilon` will work. This can be proved in general by expanding the definition of limit. The condition for the limit of `f(n)/g(n)` to approach `c` as `n` goes to infinity is that, for every `epsilon > 0`, there exists `n0` such that, for all `n > n0`, we have `|f(n)/g(n) - c| < epsilon`, which implies `f(n)/g(n) < c + epsilon`, which implies that `f(n) < (c + epsilon) g(n)`. It follows that `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`, with big-O constant `c + epsilon`.

Comment: Got it. But, I have a small doubt. Let's say I am asked to prove this. How do I go about writing it? I calculate the inequality. It doesn't satisfy. Then, do I write the argument that you wrote above or can I just write, that for big-o notation, the, value of constant should lie between, [0,inf) and therefore, it a true relation?

Comment: @Qin Just pick a bigger constant. To show that `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`, it is equally valid to show, for all sufficiently large `n`, that `f(n) <= 3 g(n)` or `f(n) <= 100000000000 g(n)`, or...